# Flutter widget testing how to mock a network image

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am trying to test my widgets, but I keep getting the 400 error on my network images. This is expected behavior because flutter doesn't want you to make http requests in a test. But because of the behaviour my widget tests fail. They have a image.network(url) in them.

I have tried with the `image_test_utils` package but discoverd quikly that this package is not maintained sinds 2018. So I came on the `Network Image Mock` package. This is maintained but isn't working: (Not my issue, but the same) https://github.com/stelynx/network_image_mock/issues/6

Now I want to try with something flutter made themselves: I added this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_markdown/blob/a2fa53b7a29dc58b6f26b53e23a6f5a8d283dd66/test/flutter_markdown_test.dart#L506-L548

But I have no clue on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

so sorry for the late answer, so i found this [dependency](https://pub.dev/packages/network_image_mock) that works perfectly with mockito.

pubspec.yaml:

```
dev_dependencies:
   network_image_mock: ^2.0.1
```

test.dart:

```
mockNetworkImagesFor(
    () async {
      return tester.pumpWidget(
        MaterialApp(
          theme: lightTheme,
          home: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: getScreenWidth(),
            height: getScreenHeight(),
            child: //widget here
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I don't work with the original code anymore but I hope people in the future may have use to it.